# In C language, how can I print 1234567890 to create a position/location ruler?

Tags: c

basically, I want to create a Position/location ruler which shows each numeric position starting at 1. let's say, if the characters in the above statement are 20 then in the next line 12345678901234567890 should be printed. similarly, if the characters are 30 then 123456789012345678901234567890 should be printed.

how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say `n` is the length you need to match

```
int n = 20; // or 30, or whatever

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) printf("%d", (i + 1) % 10);
puts(""); // add newline
```